# How to convert a decimal(6,2) value from database to a double value on a jformattedtextfield in this format **,**

Tags: java, mysql, double, jformattedtextfield

i created a jformattedtextfield to accept only numbers:

```
NumberFormat f2 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
txtformattedprice = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(f2);
```

Now i receive the value of the price from a table of my database and i want to put it in txtformattedprice:

```
rsriga.next(); //the code above is ok
txtformattedprice.setText(Double.toString((rsriga.getDouble("Price"))));
```

In my db the column "Price" is decimal(6,2) (example of a value: 14.15), if i run the application i get in txtformattedprice the value: 14.15 but i want 14,15 because if the user does a click in txtformattedprice and then he does a click in an other textfield, the value from 14.15 becomes 1.415 (now it's not a decimal).
How i can i have in the txtformattedprice 14,15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use the [`JFormattedTextField#setValue(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setValue%28java.lang.Object%29) which should use the `NumberFormat` you passed in to set the value. Something like,

```
// You may not need the cast, not sure if rsriga returns double or Double
txtformattedprice.setValue((Double) rsriga.getDouble("Price"));
```